# Data Type mismatch in criteria expression when Table Adapter Update

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, tableadapter

I have already been searched solution and can't get the right solution yet.

```
ObjDRow = DataDataSet.Client.Rows.Find(strClientNo)

With ObjDRow
      .ClientName = txtClientName.Text.Trim
      .ClientAddr = txtAddr.Text.Trim
      If txtRegOffice.Text = "" Then
         .ClientRegOfficeAddr = txtAddr.Text.Trim
      Else
         .ClientRegOfficeAddr = txtRegOffice.Text.Trim
      End If
         .MailtoCorresAddr = RBtnCorresAddr.Checked
         .MailtoRegOffice = RBtnRegOffice.Checked
         .ClientHPhone = mskHandPhone.Text.Trim
         .ClientPager = mskPagerNo.Text.Trim
         .ClientTel = mskTelephone.Text.Trim
         .ClientFaxNo = mskFax.Text.Trim
         .ClientEmail = txtEmail.Text.Trim
         .PrimaryPartner = txtPriPartner.Text.Trim
         .SecondPartner = txtSecPartner.Text.Trim
         .BroughtInBy = cboPreferredBy.Text.Trim
         .PersonIncharge = cboPersonIncharge.Text.Trim
         .GLAC = cboGLAcode.Text.Trim
         .ContactPerson = txtContactPerson.Text.Trim
         .AcraNo = txtAcraNo.Text.Trim
         .Active = chkActive.Checked

          If dtpfyear.Checked = True Then
             .YearEnd = dtpfyear.Text
          End If
          .DeptNo = cboDeptNo.Text.Trim
          .DateJoined = dtDateJoined.Value
          If cboClientName.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
              .Group = txtClientNo.Text
          Else
              .Group = cboClientName.SelectedValue
          End If
         .GroupStatus = RButtonMainYes.Checked
         .MainGroup = RButtonSubYes.Checked
         If IsDate(dtIncorporationDate.Text) Then
              .DateOfIncorporation = dtIncorporationDate.Text
         Else
              .SetDateOfIncorporationNull()
         End If
     End With
   ObjDRow.EndEdit()
 ClientTableAdapter.Update(DataDataSet.Client)
```

Error is occurs when ClientTableAdapter Update.

This error occurs for some client only.

I already check datatype of database and table adapter's datatype and all datatype are same.

My input value datatype and table adapter's datatype are same.

This error occurs even I command all line of update code (.ClientName to last line) but this error still occurs.WTF

Most answers say this is a single quote problem but In my case, There is no single quote.

All data types are same and input values are the same with `datatype`.

** Updated**

This error still occurs even I do like=>

```
ObjDRow = DataDataSet.Client.Rows.Find(strClientNo)
                ObjDRow.EndEdit()
                ClientTableAdapter.Update(DataDataSet.Client)
```

There is nothing change just select and update.

But if I remove `ObjDRow.EndEdit()`.All are fine. There is no error.

Comment: The update method requires the command to have four quieres : 1) select 2) insert 3) update 4) delete.  The commandbuilder takes the select queries and creates the other four.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can I check which column is occurs in exception?

Comment: "I already check datatype of database and table adapter's datatype and all datatype are same". That's the only thing that would cause a data type mismatch so I can only conclude that you missed something. Mind you, if the table adapter was auto-generated then that seems odd.  Perhaps you should provide ALL the relevant information, like the SQL code for each of the three action commands, the parameter data types and the database column data types. It wouldn't be the first time that someone thought that they had checked that something was correct when it wasn't.

Comment: "Can I check which column is occurs in exception?". Not directly. If you're using SQL Server then you try running SQL Profiler to see exactly what's happening at the database. You could also try setting all nullable columns to null and then provide a value for each one by one until it breaks. Also, are you only editing a row and not doing any inserting or deleting at the same time?

Comment: Yep ,I am not doing inserting and deleting. Just selecting and updating. I know this error occurs because of data type mismatching. Currently , I am using ms-access. I checked any possible way. I don't get any clue.

Comment: This error is occur even all of updating line are comment. I just only write With ObjDRow and End With and ObjDRow.EndEdit().

Comment: Can you move the endEdit to after the Update?

Comment: Its not occur error but this is not update record :(.