# Wrong inserting in MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I just want to update value in ms access table,here my query=>

```
Update Client set ClientName='COMMI' and Group='G0095C'
where ClientNo='G0095C'
```

But when i run this query, client name column of ms access insert value like that=>

[image]

why -1 value is inserted to client name column without showing an error? Why -1 value is inserted?

**I already ask question about this error last 5 day here=>[Data Type mismatchin criteria expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605576/data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression-when-table-adapter-update)

**Update**

Here are my ms access client name column properties=>

[image]

Comment: Do you have a default value for this column?

Comment: `set ClientName='COMMI', Group='G0095C'` would be the syntax I'd expect. You can check the correct syntax for an UPDATE statement in the Access documentation.

Comment: Pls check update.

Comment: It appears that you didn't learn how to write an `UPDATE` statement properly. You probably ought to read a beginners SQL tutorial to ensure that you understand the basics and won't make other such errors.

Comment: Yep @jmcilhinney, This error has come from my previous question (u commended one) .

Comment: If you're referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644992/date-filtering-in-ms-access-query-interesting) then you are using `AND` operators there in a `WHERE` clause, which is quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is:

```sql
Update Client set ClientName='COMMI', [Group]='G0095C'
where ClientNo='G0095C'
```

What you do (and what Access sees and executes) is:

```sql
Update Client set ClientName = ('COMMI' and Group='G0095C')
where ClientNo='G0095C'
```

The expression `'COMMI' and Group='G0095C'` is evaluated and returns True, so `-1` is inserted.

Note: `Group` is a [Reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845663.aspx) and must be escaped with square brackets.

Comment: but when i run like your first query,its say syntax error .

Comment: The syntax error would be because `Group` is a reserved word.  Best not to use reserved words or special characters in identifiers but, if you must, you need to escape them in SQL statements. That's done using brackets in Access.

Comment: thx for brackets, Actually I have used the comma but when I run like that, "group" is an error (I don't know "group" name is the problem in ms access) that's why I change the comma to "and ".

Comment: @jmcilhinney: that's correct, thanks.

Comment: "that's why I change the comma to "and "".  But if you understood the SQL syntax then you would know that using `AND` there makes no sense so it would have to be something else that was the problem.  Given that `GROUP BY` is part of the SQL syntax, obviously `GROUP` is a reserved word.  It's no different to naming a column `FROM` or `WHERE`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Yep u right, Thanks for pointing me out.